# Need help locating 'ekf_localization node' inside 'robot_localization' package

Tags: ekf, ros-melodic, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I naviagted to the `husky_control` package using `roscd husky_control`. There exists a launch file inside the `husky_control` package named `control.launch`.

This is how the `control.launch` file looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <arg name="multimaster" default="$(optenv ROBOT_MULTIMASTER false)"/>
  <arg name="simulation" default="$(optenv ROBOT_SIMULATION false)"/>
  <arg name="robot_namespace" default="$(optenv ROBOT_NAMESPACE robot)"/>
  <arg name="enable_ekf" default="$(optenv ENABLE_EKF true)"/>

  <arg name="config_extras"
       default="$(eval optenv('HUSKY_CONFIG_EXTRAS', find('husky_control') + '/config/empty.yaml'))"/>

  <arg name="laser_enabled" default="$(optenv HUSKY_LMS1XX_ENABLED false)"/>
  <arg name="realsense_enabled" default="$(optenv HUSKY_REALSENSE_ENABLED false)"/>
  <arg name="urdf_extras" default="$(optenv HUSKY_URDF_EXTRAS)"/>

  <include file="$(find multimaster_launch)/launch/multimaster_robot.launch" if="$(arg multimaster)">
    <arg name="gazebo_interface" value="$(find husky_control)/config/gazebo_interface.yaml" />
    <arg name="public_interface" value="$(find husky_control)/config/public_interface.yaml" />
    <arg name="robot_namespace" value="$(arg robot_namespace)"/>
    <arg name="simulation" value="$(arg simulation)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Load robot description -->
  <include file="$(find husky_description)/launch/description.launch" >
    <arg name="laser_enabled" default="$(arg laser_enabled)"/>
    <arg name="realsense_enabled" default="$(arg realsense_enabled)"/>
    <arg name="urdf_extras" default="$(arg urdf_extras)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Load controller configuration -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find husky_control)/config/control.yaml" />

  <!-- Spawn controllers -->
  <node name="base_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner"
        args="husky_joint_publisher husky_velocity_controller"/>

  <!-- Start EKF for localization -->
  <group if="$(arg enable_ekf)" >
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization">
      <rosparam command="load" file="$(find husky_control)/config/localization.yaml" />
    </node>
  </group>

  <node pkg="interactive_marker_twist_server" type="marker_server" name="twist_marker_server" output="screen"/>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

  <node pkg="twist_mux" type="twist_mux" name="twist_mux">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find husky_control)/config/twist_mux.yaml" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel_out" to="husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Override the default control parameters, see config/empty.yaml for default. -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg config_extras)" />

</launch>
```

As we can see, there's an `ekf_localization_node` inside the `robot_localization` package.  But, when I run the command `roscd robot_localization`, and navigate to the `robot_localization` package in my system, I only see the following files/folders:

```
  - cmake (folder)
  - launch (folder)
  - LICENSE
  - nodelet_plugins.xml
  - package.xml
  - params (folder)
  - srv (folder)
```

Why don't I see the `ekf_localization_node` inside the `robot_localization` package? What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365350/need-help-locating-%27ekf_localization-node%27-inside-%27robot_localization%27-package/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2020-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's because `roscd` takes you to the `share` folder of a package, but the binaries live somewhere else.

```
> ls /opt/ros/melodic/lib/robot_localization
ekf_localization_node  robot_localization_listener_node
navsat_transform_node  ukf_localization_node
```

Replace `melodic` with the name of your distro if you are on a different one.

Of course, you don't actually need to know where they are if you just want to run them. `rosrun robot_localization ekf_localization_node`  will know where to find the binary and run it.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-11**:
Thanks @chfritz.  I found it.

I have a few queries though:

- What is the significance of the `share` folder?
- It seems that I can not read the contents of the binary file. Why is that?
- Is there a way to access the code written inside `ekf_localization node`?

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-11-11**:
Yes, of course, it's an open source package: https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-11-11**:
And well, binaries are binary, so humans are not very good at reading them. You indeed are right to assume that you should be reading the source code instead.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-11**:
Got it.
Thanks!